# GridLayout not showing images in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

**So this is xml file having GridLayout inside RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorSecondary" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dal_bati"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:onClick="buyDalBati"
            android:src="@drawable/dal_bati" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gulab_jamun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:onClick="buyGulabJamun"
            android:src="@drawable/gulab_jamun" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gajar_halwa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:onClick="buyGajarHalwa"
            android:src="@drawable/gajar_halwa" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*I tried with image format jpeg, jpg and png no image format show up the images.*

Drawable folder having images
[image: Drawable folder having images]

I set the onclick listner over each image so if I click assuming that it is gonna be image here then it will open's up the next activity to buy it means onClickListener is working only the image is not showing.

**MainActivity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);

        //setting the toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Click To Buy");
        }
    }

    public void buyGajarHalwa(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GajarHalwa.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void buyGulabJamun(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GulabJamun.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void buyDalBati(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DalBati.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

And this is the theme's code

---

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.GridLayoutExperiment" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are giving android:width="wrap_content" which takes as the actual with of the image. So, please make it 0dp like below: and, also provide fixed height else it will take a whole screen. And, I have given a margin to each imageview so that it looks nice.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorSecondary" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dal_bati"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="buyDalBati"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dal_bati"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gulab_jamun"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="buyGulabJamun"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gulab_jamun"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gajar_halwa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:onClick="buyGajarHalwa"
        android:src="@drawable/gajar_halwa"
        />
   </GridLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @RudraRokaya it worked, but I didn't understand the meaning of fixed height why wrap content take the whole screen and the fact is that when I clicked to an area in screen assuming that here is my image then it will opens up the new screen from that particular area of screen not from the whole screen and if the image is  taken the size of full screen then it will opens up the new screen from any point on the screen.

Comment: according to your code you are giving parent layout height to wrap_content which means it will the height exactly the height of the child view which is imageview. And, your imageview again has the wrap_content height which means it will take the space as much the the height of the static image you are binding with it. So, in order to solve this issue, you need to provide fixed height for imageview.

Comment: but @rudra the image size is only 113 x 113 pixels.

Comment: try to play around with the code. and you will understand. And, android supports dp which is different than pixels. Just try to play with your code. If still confuses you, then let's talk in chat.